# PHP session variables do not carry across pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Hi I have created two session variables with the purpose of storing the list of ids of the query in a Comma-separated string to be broken apart into an array later. The code works fine when I was running the code on localhost with apache; however, when I upload the file on the actual server the $_SESSION variables declared in the main page never gets carried over to the second place. I did an if statement on case.php page to test it, and I also did a var_dump() and they all showed NULL.

I was wondering is there anything I need to configure with the server? As it reads PHP and does all other functions without any errors. Appreciate any help or comments.

Please see code below:

Main page: **patients.php**

```
<?php 
// store session data 
session_start(); 
// store SQL line

// store patient ID
$_SESSION['pid']='';

// store case ID
$_SESSION['cid']='';


...
while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    $patient = $record[0];
    $statusD = $record[1];
    $substatusD = $record[2];
    $caseCount = $record[3];
    $statusReason = $record[4];
    $dateReviewed = $record[5];
    $caseID = $record[6];
    $lastUser =$record[7];  

    //statusFlagged($patient,$caseID,$dateReviewed);            
    $statusFlagged = $record[8];
    //StatusFlag should be working as of 5/30/2013. Please double check

    // comma-delimited patient ID
    $_SESSION['pid'].=$patient.',';

    // comma-delimited case ID
    $_SESSION['cid'].=$caseID.',';
```

Next Page: **case.php**

```
<?php 
// start session data 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['pid'])) {
echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['pid'] . "and" . $_SESSION['cid'];
}
else { echo "Session not running";}

$patientIDString = $_SESSION['pid'];
$caseIDString = $_SESSION['cid'];
$patientIDArray = explode(',', $patientIDString);
$caseIDArray = explode(',', $caseIDString);
```

Comment: Before anything, try a simpler test: run (in the "actual server") a couple of pages that simply write and read from `$_SESSION`. This because I see that you have some extra stuff (DB reading) that must be run before setting the session values; the problem may come from that stuff (so session values may be never set).

Comment: @Racso Good idea. I tried setting the initial `$_SESSION('pid')` to 'test' and commented the variables in the while loop but still the same result. Once I'm on another page the session doesn't seem to carry on.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors when you add `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: @Pieter no not at all... which is why i think it's so weird. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837258/why-does-php-not-keep-session-between-pages/ can someone elaborate on the solution?

Comment: The only logical explanation I can see from the example code is that *$record = mysql_fetch_row($result)* evaluates to false on first run and the code inside your while loop is not executed at all. To prove me wrong, please set a session var before entering your while loop and try to access it on the next page. Let's see what happens...

Comment: Are you sure that any spaces or other code above/before your opening `PHP`-tags is removed?

Comment: @ShadowWalker that cannot be the case because the patients.php prints out a table of information based on the while loop. Plus, the session works fine on my local server

Comment: @Pieter Yes, does `// start session data` on the first line count?

Comment: @alchuang No, that shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I found the solution by making sure that the path stored in `session.save_path` under `php.ini` is accessible. Particularly if you are working with Apache. Need to make sure that the owner of the directory is the same as apache.

After changing the path and the read/write access, everything works as it should.