# PHP $_SESSION[variable] is not getting value on next page

Tags: php, session-variables

This a Login Form from where we redirect to login_success.php page when username/password match with database values.

**Checklogin.php**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['email'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM drsignup WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['email']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**Login_success.php**

This form shows a Welcome message for the user who logs in and session starts.In below code, I am not able to get $_SESSION['email'] value with Welcome string and shows undefined index email.

I tried to collect session_id from session_id();  function which gives value like e9ubrn9v239o60tfalag6e6kt4.
Please let me know why i am not able to get email id here.How can i store my session variables on my all php page.

```
<?php
session_start();

echo  session_id();
SESSION_WRITE_CLOSE();

if(isset ($_SESSION['email']))
{
echo "Welcome $_SESSION['email']";
}
else
{
header("location:Drlogin.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()` on the first page?

Comment: Add `session_start()` to config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session variables not carrying over to my logged in page, but session ID is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415005/php-session-variables-not-carrying-over-to-my-logged-in-page-but-session-id-is)

Comment: Just a quick note, why do you save the password in the session? Wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `session_start()` in `Checklogin.php`. You need to start your session on every page that uses session.